# Syntax error trying to set a property value

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to pass a  `id` from table view (`TableViewController`) to another view (`ViewController`) after tap a table cell. I have declared a storyboard ID "ViewController" for ViewController

Here is TableViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"   bundle: nil];
      UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
      viewController.id=@"test";
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

}
```

Here is ViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *id;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
       id= [[NSString alloc] init];
}
```

But the  statement `viewController.id=@"test";`  occurred the syntax error.

Comment: Make sure you create and synthesize the variable in both view controllers.

Comment: BTW - your question title is completely misleading. Your question is about a syntax error. It has nothing to do with "how to pass data between view controllers".

Answer (score 4):

`id` is a reserved word in Objective-C. Do not name any variable or property `id`. Rename it to something else.

Also, your `viewController` variable is declared as `UIViewController`. There is no `id` property in `UIViewController`. Change the type of `viewController` to the actual type it is (`ViewController`?).

```
ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)[storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
```

Comment: While it's probably not a good idea to name a property `id`, it is actually possible (`id` is a `typedef`, not a keyword). I'm a bit surprised though, that the syntax error is not in the line `id = [[NSString alloc] init]`, because the synthesized ivar name would be `_id`.

Comment: @omz Regarding `id` vs `_id` - it depends on whether the OP has `@sythensize id` or if they explicitly declared an ivar named `id`.

Comment: @rmaddy Since there was no `@synthesize` statement in the code, I assumed he used the default synthesis, which would generate `_id`. But either way, `viewController.id=@"test";` shouldn't generate a syntax error.

Comment: @omz Yes, `viewController.id=@"test";` should generate a syntax error since `viewController` is declared as a `UIViewController`, not as the more specific class that actually defines the property.

Answer (score 1):

Check the link below, covers these basics for beginners on how to pass data between UITableViewController to another view.

[Storyboards Segue Tutorial: Pass Data Between View Controllers](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/)

By the way, i don't think you can use "id" as your property name.